# WPF ComboBox resets selected item when item-source changes

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem

Consider the following XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="CompanyComboBox" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GlobalData.Companies}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Customer.CompanyId, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

`GlobalData.Companies` is a collection (`IEnumerable<Company>`) of companies; this collection can be reloaded on background (it is downloaded from a webservice). When this happens, ComboBox correctly reloads items via binding. However as a side-effect, it also resets the selected item!

I have used Reflector to inspect combo-box sources and apparently this is intended behavior.

Is there any "nice" way how to get around this? What I want to achieve, is that if the user selects "Company A" and reloads list of companies afterwards, then "Company A" stays selected (assuming it is in the new list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use `ObservableCollection<Company>` instead of your `IEnumerable<Company>`? Then, on background change you would only Add / Remove items that are new / absent in the new list, selected item should stay, unless it was removed by the change.

You can [update your observable collection in a separate thread with a small hack-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104614/updating-an-observablecollection-in-a-separate-thread).

Comment: This could be the solution, although it isn't as nice/easy as I would like to :-|

Comment: It's probably not necessary to update the collection from the background thread.  Get the current collection from the web service in the background, and then (assuming you're using a BackgroundWorker) update the `ObservableCollection<Company>` in the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Answer (score 12):

Please try with the following code.
Enable the following property to the combo box

`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`

Answer (score 1):

hmm, I don't know if it is a "nice" way, but if you can access the selected item before the reload occurs, you can save it (or its key or something), and select it programatically again after the reload is done.

quick mockup:

```
var selectedItem = myCombo.SelectedItem;
DoReload();
myCombo.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
```

But I assume you mean another way than this manual work around?
Hope this helps anyway...

**UPDATE**
Ok I see, from a background thread.
Are you using an ICollectionView to bind your combobox too? If so, you can use the CurrentItem property to keep a reference. I made a quick mockup, and this is working on my setup. this assumes you have a reference to your UI:

*XAML*

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">  
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">Update</Button>
</Grid>
```

*View/ViewModel*

```
public partial class Window1 : Window {
   public Window1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel(this);
   }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly Window1 window;
    private ObservableCollection<Item> items;
    private ICollectionView view;

    public ViewModel(Window1 window) {
        this.window = window;
        items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
            {
                new Item("qwerty"),
                new Item("hello"),
                new Item("world"),
            };

        view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get { return items; } }

    public ICommand UpdateCommand {
        get { return new RelayCommand(DoUpdate); }
    }

    public Item SelectedItem { get; set; }

    private void DoUpdate(object obj) {
        var act = new Func<List<Item>>(DoUpdateAsync);
        act.BeginInvoke(CallBack, act);
    }

    private List<Item> DoUpdateAsync() {
        return new List<Item> {
                new Item("hello"),
                new Item("world"),
                new Item("qwerty"),
            };
    }

    private void CallBack(IAsyncResult result) {
        try {
            var act = (Func<List<Item>>)result.AsyncState;
            var list = act.EndInvoke(result);

            window.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<List<Item>>(delegate(List<Item> lst) {
                                                                    var current = lst.Single(i => i.Name == ((Item)view.CurrentItem).Name);
                                                                    Items.Clear();
                                                                    lst.ForEach(Items.Add);
                                                                    view.MoveCurrentTo(current);
                                                                }), list);

        } catch(Exception exc){ Debug.WriteLine(exc); }
    }
}

public class Item {
    public Item(string name) {
        Name = name; 
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You will need to do some handling in case the selected item is no longer in the list.
The **IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem** property is important here, else it won't work!
Also, the way the reference to the main window is made should be by a DI-framework.

Comment: The trouble is that DoReload() is performed on background by a class that has no idea about the GUI.

The GUI is notified about the new values via Binding & INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: If the description of the selected value can change during the refresh, add "my_Combo.SelectedIndex = -1" after the DoReload().  This will cause the description displayed to refresh when the selected index is updated after resetting the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

As Yacoder pointed out this has to do with object equality. As long as you bind SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem you can define the ItemsSource as an anonymous type collection. Then this problem will not occur (and it is also faster if you need to read the values from a database).